# Crear un trigger para ejecutar diferentes procedimientos dependiendo del valor insertado

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Quiero crear un trigger para ejecutar diferentes procedimientos almacenados dependiendo del valor de una columna de la fila insertada

Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerActualizarDatos ON tDatos AFTER insert AS
BEGIN
IF INSERTED.value LIKE '12201%'
    EXEC [_actualizarDatos_12201]
ELSEIF INSERTED.value LIKE '12049%'
    EXEC [_actualizarDatos_12049]
END
```

Pero me da error de sintaxos

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que INSERTED es una tabla y tienes que acceder a su información de la manera tradicional. También debes de tener en cuenta que el valor de una columna no es un valor escalar, por lo que debes de estar preparado para manejar múltiples filas a la vez.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo que puede servir.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerActualizarDatos ON tDatos AFTER insert AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE value LIKE '12201%')
        EXEC [_actualizarDatos_12201];

    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INSERTED WHERE value LIKE '12049%')
        EXEC [_actualizarDatos_12049];
END
```